# How to pass a number from app.js to index.html? I can pass a static text, but need to pass a calculated number or number from an array

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

How to pass a number from app.js to index.html?  I can pass a static text, but need to pass a calculated number or number from an array.  This is my code that works for passing a static string.

``d3.select("li").text("score")

It successfully updates the desired 'li' tag of my html, and displays 'score'  without quotes on the webpage.

But I do not know how to modify the code to instead of 'score', display a number that is calculated inside my javascript code (app.js). Or alternatively how to modify the code to pass a number from an array inside app.js to the html.  Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set anything as text parameter. It should display correctly without any problem.

```js
function updateScore(){
    let computedValue = Math.random();
    d3.select("li").text(computedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but that does not work.  I had tried that before submitting my question to stack overflow.  When I did what you said, it placed "" in the li tag.  that is what got displayed on the index.html:  "".

To clarify...I only used .text to experiment passing a static string to the 'li' tag.  I just cannot find the appropriate syntax for passing a calculated value or a value  from a single cell of an array to the 'li' tag.  That is what I need help with.

Comment: Can you share the snippet.? Then only I may be able to help you..

Comment: My mistake Kumar.  Your solution works.  My code to index the proper cell in the array inside my app.js was wrong.  I fixed it and it works.  Thank you.